# Extract string without spacing in powershell cmdlet

Tags: string, powershell, comparison

I have some powershell script . Instead totalcmd* you can type another process you want.

```
$tc = get-process -Name totalcmd* | format-wide -property Name 
echo $tc
if ($tc -eq "Totalcmd64")
{
Stop-Process -Name totalcmd*
}
Start-Sleep 10
```

It doesn't work, I think, because, my $tc not equal to string "totalcmd". How can I remove unwanted spaces of cmdlet `get-process -Name totalcmd* | format-wide -property Name` output and compare strings correctly?

Comment: If you end up with more than one process that starts with "totalcmd", then your "if" statement will never evaluate to true because the array object `$tc` will never equal a string object "Totalcmd64".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not end up with a string because you pipe to `format-wide`. These cmdlets are best for representing data on the screen. Instead select the property and use `-ExpandProperty` to return it as a string:

```
$tc = get-process -Name totalcmd* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name 
echo $tc
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are generally correct that $tc is not equal to "totalcmd" and that is because when you set $tc, you are creating an array (most likely of one element). You can test that by running `$tc | get-member` to see what kind of object you are working with.

To work with string objects, you could use the `Out-String` cmdlet as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly stop TotalCmd64 processes why not simply use:

```
Get-Process -Name TotalCmd64 | Stop-Process
```

If you want to switch between 64/32bit versions of the program, use a switch statement (untested):

```
$tc = (Get-Process -Name TotalCmd*).Name
switch ($tc){
    'TotalCmd'   {Get-Process -Name TotalCmd  |Stop-Process;"Start TotalCmd64";Break}
    'TotalCmd64' {Get-Process -Name TotalCmd64|Stop-Process;"Start TotalCmd32";Break}
    default      {"No TotalCmd* processes found"}
}
```

Comment: May be you right. Globally, I need script for  restart Totalcmd64.exe to Totalcmd.exe and vice versa.

Comment: See extended answer to switch between 64/32bit versions.